# How to extract SEVRAL URLs from 1 Google Sheets field that are NOT formatted as hyperlinks

Tags: google-sheets

I have a problem extracting several URLs from a field in Google sheets and have them displayd in the next columns automatically. The field is a regular text field and the links are in that field as you may see here (not formatted as hyperlinks):

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VYGEHO7FIQU6mjZ-ltJJcWAIjpni6cmbxZGuKSznKbo/edit?usp=sharing

I am trying to get some automation working and would need the URLs to be displayd in separate columns with a formula or script withthe results being as I put manually in my example file...

Hope someone can help me solve this :)

Thank you !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(
 REGEXREPLACE(SPLIT(A2:A3, CHAR(10)&"<>", 1)&"♦", 
 "^\s♦|^\.\.\.\s?♦", )="",,
 REGEXREPLACE(SPLIT(A2:A3, CHAR(10)&"<>", 1)&"♦", 
 "^\s♦|^\.\.\.\s?♦", )&"♦")),,9^9)), "♦", 0, 1)))
```

[image]

Comment: wow !!! works perfectly. Thank you very very much...

Comment: The above formula uses [SPLIT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136?hl=en) , [TRIM](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094140?hl=en) and [CHAR](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094120?hl=en) along with [REGEXREPLACE]() to replace and split into difference cells plain text from the URL strings that start off with ```<>```. [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275) is used to return a range of values rather than a single value.